# Capturar erro quando clica no botão

Tags: c#, .net, banco-de-dados, exceção, ado.net

Quero fazer um botão que quando é clicado é mostrado as informações do SQL Server e dizer que ele está conectado (tem que configurar o arquivo no XML Configuration File)

Vejam abaixo o código:

```
public class Functions
{
    public static void conn()
    {
        string connectionString = Conn.tank();
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            bool Open = true;
            if (Open)
            {
                connection.Open();
                Globals.UpdateLogs("Conexão testada:");
                Globals.UpdateLogs("Status da Conexão : " + connection.State);  //info
                Globals.UpdateLogs("User : " + connection.WorkstationId);  //info
                Globals.UpdateLogs("Banco de dados : " + connection.Database);  //info
                Globals.UpdateLogs("Versão SQL : " + connection.ServerVersion); //info
            }
            else
            {
                Globals.UpdateLogs("O programa não está conectado em sua DataBase, verifique as configurações");
            }

        }
    }
```

No caso ele funciona certinho quando aperta o botão e os dados estão certos ele diz as configurações mais quando está errado os dados do SQL Server, ele para de funcionar o programa.

Peguei um código já pronto só estou tentando deixá-lo melhor, mas não consigo fazer "Se os dados estiver errado mostre a mensagem".

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se entendi bem o que deseja e nem mesmo se esse código faz sentido, mas seria mais ou menos isso que acho que deseja:

```
public class Functions {
    public static void conn() {
        string connectionString = Conn.tank();
        var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        try {
            connection.Open();
            Globals.UpdateLogs("Conexão testada:");
            Globals.UpdateLogs("Status da Conexão : " + connection.State);
            Globals.UpdateLogs("User : " + connection.WorkstationId);
            Globals.UpdateLogs("Banco de dados : " + connection.Database);
            Globals.UpdateLogs("Versão SQL : " + connection.ServerVersion);
        } catch (SystemException ex) {
            if (ex is InvalidOperationException || ex is SqlException || ex is ConfigurationErrorsException) {
                Globals.UpdateLogs("O programa não está conectado em sua DataBase, verifique as configurações");
            }
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                ((IDisposable)connection).Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Exception/SqlError.cs).

Certamente tem maneiras melhores de fazer isso, mas teria que pensar no *design* como um todo.

Para C# 5 ou anterior:

```
public class Functions {
    public static void conn() {
        string connectionString = Conn.tank();
        var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        try {
            connection.Open();
            Globals.UpdateLogs("Conexão testada:");
            Globals.UpdateLogs("Status da Conexão : " + connection.State);
            Globals.UpdateLogs("User : " + connection.WorkstationId);
            Globals.UpdateLogs("Banco de dados : " + connection.Database);
            Globals.UpdateLogs("Versão SQL : " + connection.ServerVersion);
        } catch (InvalidOperationException ex) {
            Globals.UpdateLogs("O programa não está conectado em sua DataBase, verifique as configurações");
        } catch (SqlException  ex) {
            Globals.UpdateLogs("pode por uma mensagem mais específica aqui");
        } catch (ConfigurationErrorsException ex) {
            Globals.UpdateLogs("pode por uma mensagem mais específica aqui");
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                ((IDisposable)connection).Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Na 4 linha deu erro: ; expected e quando coloco ; da erro e na "ex is ConfigurationErrorsExeception da erro que não foi encontrado

Comment: Tinha um erro de digitação. Está usando C# 6? Se não está, vai ficar mais complicado. Como você não fez um [mcve], e como eu não sei como você aplicou, eu não tenho como ajudar muito mais que isso.

Comment: Estou usando o VisualStudio 2012 não sei se tem o C# 6, se não tiver tem como instalar?

Comment: Não tem, recomendo usar algo mais novo. Coloquei como fica em C# antigo.