# Bloco using e Exceções

Tags: c#, exceção, using

Existe alguma maneira de relatar erros em códigos no bloco `using` assim como no `try` temos o `catch`? Ou utilizando o `using` estou preso a uma infinidade de `if`, `else if` e `else`?

Supondo que o bloco `using` te obrigue a criar muitas condições, qual vocês preferem? `try, catch e finally` ou `using, if, else if e else`?

Comment: O `using` serve para uma coisa, o `if` e `else` para outra e o `try`, `catch` e `finally` para uma terceira coisa. Tecnicamente, a pergunta não faz sentido. Semanticamente, quando você diz '_o que vocês preferem?_' automaticamente colocaria a pergunta - caso fizesse sentido - fora do escopo do site. Talvez possamos ajudar se você apresentar um caso específico na prática.

Comment: o using nada mais é que um bloco para restrição de escopo e dispose, todo o resto são instruções que não tem nada a ver isso.

Comment: `Using` cria um escopo que é destruído no final, correto? Mas se eu preciso saber se determinado escopo foi executado corretamente ou não, como `using` me retornaria se alguma exceção fosse encontrada?. `try` tenta, `catch` relata e `finally` finaliza. Como relatar exceções em um bloco `using`?

Comment: Procurando por links achei isso e acho que é duplicata: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/165632/101

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O `using` realmente é um `finally` implícito e não permite um `catch`. Até há quem peça para ter, mas duvido que um dia tenha. A solução quando precisa capturar uma exceção que pode ocorrer em um bloco que trabalha com um recursos que deve ser dispensado no final da sua execução é usar um `try-catch-finally` mesmo.

Só cuidado porque eu vejo captura de exceções sendo abusada, em muitos casos não precisaria ou até mesmo a exceção não deveria ser lançada.

Outro problema comum é que as pessoas não entendem bem o que deve fazer no `finally` para chamar o método `Dispose()`.

```
{
    var arq = new FileStream("arq.txt", FileMode.Create);
    try {
        //faz alguma coisa aqui
    } finally {
        if (arq != null) ((IDisposable)arq).Dispose();
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Exception/DisposePattern.cs).

O `if` pode ser usado em alguns contextos, depende do que está querendo tratar, se usa o `if` adequadamente então o `using` provavelmente será usado.

Eu dei uma [resposta sobre o assunto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/204637/101).

Em C# 8 pode fazer:

```
var using arq = new FileStream("arq.txt", FileMode.Create);
```

O bloco será o escopo atual, assim não precisaria criar um novo bloco como precisava antes.

Comment: Exatamente isso que eu queria saber. É correto afirmar que esse código `using (var arq = new FileStream("arq.txt", FileMode.Create)) { //faz alguma coisa }` tem a mesma função que seu código acima?

Comment: Esqueci do `FileStream` :)  É correto afirmar.

Answer (score 2):

Pera aí, deixa eu explicar.

### using

é para quando você irá usar um objeto e em seguida descartá-lo sem armazenar informação na memória.

```
using (StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder()) {
    sb.AppendLine("Olá, mundo!");
}
// o StringBuilder sb não existe mais na memória
```

Ele é usado somente com objetos que implementam `IDisposeable` (objeto descartável). O bloco `using` não implementa nenhuma expressão de condição nem de exceções.

---

### try

é usado quando você irá capturar erros de runtime dentro de um bloco e irá manipulá-los.

```
int valor = 0;
try {
    // tente fazer isso
    valor = Convert.ToInt32("Isso não é um número");
} catch (Exception ex) {
    // se der erro, faça isso com o erro:
    Console.WriteLine("Não deu certo, pois " + ex.Message);
    valor = 10;
} finally {
    // no final, mesmo se der certo ou der erro,
    valor *= 2;
}
```

No final, valor será *20*, pois dentro do bloco irá dar um erro para converter aquela string para um número. No bloco `catch`, é atribuído o valor *10* para *valor*, e no bloco `finally`, é multiplicado por dois o valor.

Não é recomendável usar `try`, mas somente quando você irá fazer uma coisa que precisa de manipulação do usuário.

---

### if

esse é o clássico condicional, ele só irá executar o que está dentro do bloco se a expressão for *true*:

```
if(1 + 1 == 2) {
     Console.WriteLine("Isso irá executar");
}
if(2 + 2 == 5) {
     Console.WriteLine("Isso não irá executar");
}
```

Claro que foram usados valores óbvios e constantes no exemplo acima, mas o bloco `if` aceita variáveis e constantes, desde que o valor final seja `Boolean`.

---

### Onde usar tudo isso?

Você pode combinar os três blocos acima, um dentro do outro, cada um desempenhando uma função. Você apenas precisa entender o que cada um faz.

Dá uma lida na [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/index).